# Help in finding the domain of a cardboard

Tags: functions

the question goes like this

> An open box is to be made from a 16 inch by 30 inch in piece of cardboard by cutting out squares of equal size from the four corners and bending up the sides. FIND ITS DOMAIN

I've calculated its volume that is 
**V = (x) (16-2x) (30-2x)**
and since x is a length, its domain must be equal or greater than 0.
but in the answer key it is written that the x is less and equal to 8.
my question is "why"? 
Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need **all** the lengths to be positive, hence, we need $$x \ge 0$$

$$16-2x \ge 0$$

$$30-2x \ge 0$$

Comment: A.K.A. $8 \ge x \ge 0$